# Update microsoft excel single cell to database

Tags: sql-server, excel

i already pull data from sql server, with 2 blank column.
my requirement is :
when user enter value into a single cell in these 2 columns, it will update database base on primary key (specific column's value in same row).

would it able to do like this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If updating cell by cell is really a requirement, I suggest you create a procedure in SQL Server that accepts the cell value as a parameter. However, it would probably be better to wait until all relevant cells have been completed and ask the user to click a button to update. You will need to do a good deal of checking to ensure that data is not sent twice. It is also possible to work from the SQL server end.